# Why can't I get this mp4 to play in my source video tags?

Tags: html, video, tags

I have demo mp4 videos that play but I can't get the one for my project working. I've been working on this for an embarassingly long time and I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing at this point.

My code is:

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" style="width:100%; height: auto; position:absolute; z-index: -1;">
                <source src="http://files.parsetfss.com/90b6030c-d712-42ec-b2ee…fss-4d5fe3b4-8758-4fb6-a11b-585987a74f56-Date.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>

                <!--<source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>-->
                <!--<source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>-->
                <!--<source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>-->
                <!--<source src="http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/assets/tunnel_animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">-->

              </video>
```

All of the commented out videos are demos that work just fine. Mine works on my machine when I open it and press play but not remotely or within my project.

I also tried it with and without the listed codecs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL to the mp4 is [not accessible](https://validator.w3.org/checklink?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.parsetfss.com%2F90b6030c-d712-42ec-b2ee%E2%80%A6fss-4d5fe3b4-8758-4fb6-a11b-585987a74f56-Date.mp4&hide_type=all&depth=&check=Check).

`2ee…fss`

I believe the dots might not be part of the filename. But only you can check that if you own the server.